# ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess on Embedded Form Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activesupport

I'm getting an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` error when I try to update an embedded form.

Here's the simplest example:

Form:

```
<h1>PlayersToTeams#edit</h1>
<%= form_for @players_to_teams do |field| %>
    <%= field.fields_for @players_to_teams.player do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :IsActive %>
        <%= f.text_field :IsActive %>
    <% end %>
    <%= field.label :BT %>
    <%= field.text_field :BT %>
    <br/>
    <%= field.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :players_to_teams
end
```

Controller:

```
class PlayersToTeamsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @players_to_teams=PlayersToTeam.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @players_to_teams=PlayersToTeam.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @players_to_teams.update_attributes(params[:players_to_team])
        format.html { redirect_to @players_to_teams, notice: 'Player_to_Team was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @players_to_teams.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the `params[:players_to_team]` object upon form submission:

[image: :players_to_team]

What does an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` error mean? What do I need to do to have this form update the `players_to_team` entry?

**Edit**

`BT` is a column in `players_to_teams`.  If I remove teh `field_for` block, I can successfully save the `BT` field/the `players_to_teams` row.

Thanks

Comment: what is the attribute "BT" -- is that the correct name of a field on the table players_to_teams ?

Comment: Yea. Question updated to provide more info.

Comment: can you change "<%= field.fields_for @players_to_teams.player" to "<%= field.fields_for :player"

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it works.  Do you have any idea why that is? I posted about it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021980/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-fields-for

Comment: SInce you created a nearly identical question, you should delete this one

Comment: what software are you using in the ruby trace above?

Comment: @ijverig rubymine - http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/.  I love it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credit goes to @Brandan.  Answered: [What is the difference between using ":" and "@" in fields_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021980/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-fields-for)

> Okay, I was able to clone your sample project and reproduce the error.
>   I think I understand what's happening.
>
> After your call to accepts_nested_attributes_for, you now have an
>   instance method on your model named `player_attributes=`. This is in
>   addition to the `player=` method that's normally defined for a `has_one`
>   association. The `player_attributes=` method accepts a hash of
>   attributes, whereas the `player=` method only accepts an actual Player
>   object.
>
> Here's an example of the text input generated when you called
>   `fields_for @players_to_teams.player`:
>
> `<input name="players_to_team[player][name]" ... />` and here's that
>   same input when calling `fields_for :player`:
>
> `<input name="players_to_team[player_attributes][name]" ... />` When you
>   call `update_attributes` in your controller, the first example will call
>   `player=`, while the second example will call `player_attributes=`. In
>   both cases, the argument passed to the method is a hash (because
>   params is ultimately just a hash of hashes).
>
> That's why you were getting an `AssociationTypeMismatch`: you can't pass
>   a hash to `player=`, only a Player object.
>
> It appears that the only safe way to use `fields_for` with
>   `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is by passing the name of the
>   association and not the association itself.
>
> So to answer your original question, the difference is that one works
>   and the other doesn't :-)