# What is the difference between using ":" and "@" in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am setting up embedded forms in my rails app.

This does not work

```
<h1>PlayersToTeams#edit</h1>
<%= form_for @players_to_teams do |field| %>
  <%= field.fields_for @players_to_teams.player do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :IsActive %>
    <%= f.text_field :IsActive %>
  <% end %>
  <%= field.label :BT %>
  <%= field.text_field :BT %>
  <br/>
  <%= field.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Gives me a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` error.  Notice the `@players_to_teams.player` in the `forms_for` line.

This does work:

```
<h1>PlayersToTeams#edit</h1>
<%= form_for @players_to_teams do |field| %>
    <%= field.fields_for :player do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :IsActive %>
        <%= f.text_field :IsActive %>
    <% end %>
    <%= field.label :BT %>
    <%= field.text_field :BT %>
    <br/>
    <%= field.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the `:player` call in the `fields_for` line.

Whats the difference between using a symbol and using an instance? I would think I would want to use an instance in this case, but I guess not?

**Edit**

models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :players_to_teams
end

class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :player
end
```

controller:

```
class PlayersToTeamsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @players_to_teams=PlayersToTeam.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @players_to_teams=PlayersToTeam.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @players_to_teams.update_attributes(params[:players_to_team])
        format.html { redirect_to @players_to_teams, notice: 'Player_to_Team was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @players_to_teams.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example Project**

Github: https://github.com/workmaster2n/embedded-form-errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `fields_for` can't figure out what the `player` association is for the `@players_to_teams` instance variable. You bypass that by explicitly specifying the name of the association (i.e., `:player`). Are you defining the association in both directions? I.e.:

```
class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :players_to_team
end
```

Additionally, looking at [the documentation for `fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), the first parameter is called `record_name`, so it seems like Rails is expecting the *name* of the association rather than the association itself. But it's hard to tell exactly what that method does without looking further into the code, and some of their examples do indeed pass the association directly into `fields_for`.

---

Okay, I was able to clone your sample project and reproduce the error. I think I understand what's happening.

After your call to [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for), you now have an instance method on your model named `player_attributes=`. This is in addition to the `player=` method that's normally defined for a `has_one` association. The `player_attributes=` method accepts a hash of attributes, whereas the `player=` method only accepts an actual `Player` object.

Here's an example of the text input generated when you called `fields_for @players_to_teams.player`:

```
<input name="players_to_team[player][name]" ... />
```

and here's that same input when calling `fields_for :player`:

```
<input name="players_to_team[player_attributes][name]" ... />
```

When you call `update_attributes` in your controller, the first example will call `player=`, while the second example will call `player_attributes=`. In both cases, the argument passed to the method is a hash (because `params` is ultimately just a hash of hashes).

That's why you were getting an `AssociationTypeMismatch`: you can't pass a hash to `player=`, only a `Player` object.

It appears that the only safe way to use `fields_for` with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is by passing the name of the association and not the association itself.

So **to answer your original question**, the difference is that one works and the other doesn't :-)

Comment: I've added my models to my question.  The only thing I can see on the documentation is when they use an instance variable for the first parameter, they aren't bound inside of another `form_for` block.

Comment: In their first "generic example", they actually do use `fields_for` with an explicit association within a `form_for`. I was also able to create a simple app with similar models and a similar form, and it didn't generate that error. Looking at the Rails source, it seems like the only time you should receive an `AssociationTypeMismatch` exception is when you're *assigning* an object as an association and the class of the object doesn't match the class of the association. Are you doing anything like that anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning an object as an association"?  I don't think I'm doing anything abnormal, but maybe I am.  I've added the controller source just in case.

Comment: See [the docs on AssociationTypeMismatch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationTypeMismatch.html) (got the link right this time :-). The example is assigning a `Comment` object to an association defined for `Patch` objects. Where are you seeing the exception? When generating the form (in the view) or when submitting the form (in the controller)?

Comment: I just tried a sample app and am getting the same error.  Maybe you could take a look at the GitHub project I linked to and see where my difference is?

Comment: Looks like we commented at the same time.  I get the exception once I submit the form to the update function.  It happens on the update_attributes line (as far as I can tell from the debugger).  I should be assigning a player to the players_to_teams instance.  That is, I don't think I'm doing something like the example in the link.